# CS50 library in C

Tags: c, installation, cs50

I am new to Ubuntu and new to C programming. Now I am watching cs50 videos to understand better about C and CS all together.
I tried to install this by using these guidelines:

Debian, Ubuntu

First become root, as with:

```
sudo su -
```

Then install the CS50 Library as follows:

```
apt-get install gcc
wget http://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/library50-c-5.zip
unzip library50-c-5.zip
rm -f library50-c-5.zip
cd library50-c-5
gcc -c -ggdb -std=c99 cs50.c -o cs50.o
ar rcs libcs50.a cs50.o
chmod 0644 cs50.h libcs50.a
mkdir -p /usr/local/include
chmod 0755 /usr/local/include
mv -f cs50.h /usr/local/include
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
chmod 0755 /usr/local/lib
mv -f libcs50.a /usr/local/lib
cd ..
rm -rf library50-c-5
```

I used it, and I think everything went as planned, but as soon as I try to run `gcc demo.c` I get a fatal error message:

```
adder.c:2:18: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory
#include <cs50.h>
```

So as it seems that somewhere something went wrong and I don't really know how to fix it.  Could anyone guide me a little bit how to fix it or how reinstall everything that C automatically would include that library?

Comment: How did you include your code? The commands seem alright. I would recommend `sudo apt-get install clang`, and then try re-installing the library.

Comment: This is how Unix/Linux has always 'worked'.  You try to install stuff, then get confusing and unintelligible error messages:)

Comment: Newly created directories may not be contained to configuration. Did you check your environment variables?

Comment: Well i tried to  re-write everything, without su - command, just get bunch of  access denied.
How would i need to check environment variables?

Comment: where is the `demo.c` file located?

Comment: is the `cs50.h` file in the directory `/usr/local/include/` as it should be located when this line was executed: `mv -f cs50.h /usr/local/include`

Comment: Other than I do not have the `demo.c` file,  I ran the sequence of steps you used.  (I already have the directories `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` so skipped those  steps that create and set the permissions on those directories.   I already have `gcc` and the 'essential tools` so skipped those steps. it worked very well for me when I created a demo.c file for some testing of the cs50 library.  Even a 'just installed' linux distribution should have everything but the cs50 components.  How did you install linux?

Answer (score 1):

check in the /usr/local/include directory for the cs50.h file

If it was not there, then one or more of the shell commands failed (or was skipped).

have you tried running `gcc` to compile/link the `demo.c` file via:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99 demo.c -o demo.o -I/usr/local/include
gcc demo.o -o demo -L/usr/local/lib -lcs50
```

If your not sure what the above two lines do, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for help, just installed windows and now using it on virtual machine. Gonna go back on linux then i will gain more understanding about it cause now it just to confusing to operate in them for me.

Answer (score 0):

<CS50.h> exist on the CS50 IDE only. The functions it contains are string as a type def and the get functions.

If you use char * instead of string type

and

scanf() instead of get_(type)

You do not need it.

If you do need it I would just use the IDE in the course. It's free and halfway through the course they take the training wheels off.

Comment: Good point Mike. People really need to stop babying C, its not that complex once you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-lcs50` in the end. Also specify the file where you want the machine code output using the `-o` parameter.

Run this to compile the program: `gcc demo.c -o demo -lcs50`

Run this to execute the program: `./demo`